# Is there any way to visually notify the user that nothing has been set for the mat-button-toggle-group?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a required mat-button-toggle-group inside of a stepper component form, but when nothing is selected, there is no visual indication to the user that this was the field that needed to be filled in. Here is my mat-button-toggle-group:

```
<h4>Choose a dog size *</h4>
<mat-button-toggle-group required matInput formControlName="dogCtrl" name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
      <mat-button-toggle value="small">Small</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="medium">Medium</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="large">Large</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="giant">Giant</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

From what I understand, it is also not possible to put the group inside a mat-form-field either. When I try to do so, I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
```

I'm new to Angular so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to do it. This way is better because it does not modify the typescript file at all, and leaves all validation to the Validators.

To do this, I added two things to the form.

1. To know whether the user attempted to submit the form, the form needs to be referenceable. This is done by adding the #form1="ngForm" inside the form tag.
2. To modify the appearance of the mat-button-toggle-group, the group is given a class if it is submitted and the form control is not valid.

```
<form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup" #form1="ngForm">
  <div [ngClass]="{'mat-form-field-invalid' : form1.submitted && firstFormGroup.controls.dogsizeCtrl.invalid}">
      <label id="dogSizeLabel">My Dog Size *</label>
      <mat-button-toggle-group required matInput formControlName="dogsizeCtrl" name="dogSize" aria-labelledby="dogSizeLabel" multiple="false">
        <mat-button-toggle value="small">Small<span>0-15 lbs</span></mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="medium">Medium<span>16-40 lbs</span></mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="large">Large<span>40-100 lbs</span></mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="giant">Giant<span>101+ lbs</span></mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
  </div>
  <div>
      <button mat-raised-button matStepperNext color="primary">Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Then, to change the appearance of the mat-button-toggle-group, the class that was added is described in the scss:

```
.mat-form-field-invalid mat-button-toggle-group {
 background-color: red;
}

.mat-form-field-invalid label {
  color:red ;
}
```

The appearance goes from this when the page is loaded:
[image]

To this when the user attempts to submit the form when the dog size has not been selected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather hacky solution.

Within the component's typescript file, I added the function firstForm() and the boolean nextClicked into the component's OnInit:

```
export class SearchStepsComponent implements OnInit {
  firstFormGroup!: FormGroup;
  nextClicked = false;
  get firstForm(){
    return this.firstFormGroup.controls;
  }
}
```

Within the stepper form, I added a mat-error with an ngIf* statement checking whether the form control is valid and whether the next button at the bottom of the form has been clicked. I added an onClick function to the button to keep track of this.

```
<h4>Choose a dog size *</h4> <mat-error *ngIf="form.dogCtrl.errors?.required && nextClicked==true">dog size is required</mat-error>
<mat-button-toggle-group required matInput formControlName="dogCtrl" name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
    <mat-button-toggle value="small">Small</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="medium">Medium</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="large">Large</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="giant">Giant</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>

<div>
    <button mat-button (click)="nextClicked=true" matStepperNext>Next</button>
</div>
```

This is not the most elegant code, but it is functional and looks like this in the end:

looks like this on page load:

[image]

Looks like this when the "Next" button is clicked:

[image]

The red text goes away when a size is chosen from the mat-button-toggle-group. When all form controls are valid, the next button does go to the next step in the stepper.

If anyone can think of a more elegant solution, I'd love to see it and would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

**Hack**: wrap the mat-button-toggle-group with a mat-form-field.

**Trick**: a hidden `matInput` with the same `mat-button-toggle-group` `formControlName` value must be included

**Note**: the current Angular Material Version (12.2.10) does not allow `<input type="hidden" matInput>`, so hack it with `display:none` in your css class or style tag.

```
<form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>My Dog Size *</mat-label>
    <input style="display: none" formControlName="dogsizeCtrl" matInput />
    <mat-button-toggle-group
      required
      matInput
      formControlName="dogsizeCtrl"
      name="dogSize"
      aria-labelledby="dogSizeLabel"
      multiple="false"
    >
      <mat-button-toggle value="small">Small<span>0-15 lbs</span></mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="medium">Medium<span>16-40 lbs</span></mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="large">Large<span>40-100 lbs</span></mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="giant">Giant<span>101+ lbs</span></mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div>
    <button mat-raised-button matStepperNext color="primary">Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```